# How to show that $dX_{t} = \sqrt{2c\lambda} dB_{t}-\lambda X_{t}dt$ has the following solution

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $B$ be the brownian motion. How can I show that $dX_{t} = \sqrt{2c\lambda} dB_{t}-\lambda X_{t}dt$ is solved by

$$ X_{t}=X_{0}e^{-\lambda t}+\sqrt{2c\lambda}\int\limits_{0}^{t}e^{-\lambda(t-s)}dB_{s}$$

My attempt:

I wanted to use Ito's formula, more particularly, the integration by parts formula:

$$e^{\lambda t}X_{t}=X_{0}+\int\limits_{0}^{t}e^{\lambda s}dX_{s}+\int\limits_{0}^{t}X_{s}d(e^{\lambda s})=X_{0}+\int\limits_{0}^{t}e^{\lambda s}dX_{s}+\int\limits_{0}^{t}X_{s}\lambda e^{\lambda s}ds\\=X_{0}+\int\limits_{0}^{t}e^{\lambda s}(X_{0}e^{-\lambda s}+\sqrt{2c\lambda}\int\limits_{0}^{s}e ^{-\lambda(s-u)}dB_{u})ds+\int\limits_{0}^{t}X_{s}\lambda e^{\lambda s}ds \\= X_{0}+\int\limits_{0}^{t}(X_{0}+\sqrt{2c\lambda}\int\limits_{0}^{s}e^{\lambda u}dB_{u})ds+\int\limits_{0}^{t}X_{s}\lambda e^{\lambda s}ds$$

then multiplying by $e^{-\lambda t}$, we obtain:

$$X_{t}=e^{-\lambda t}X_{0}+\int\limits_{0}^{t}(e ^{-\lambda t}X_{0}+\sqrt{2c\lambda}\int\limits_{0}^{s}e^{-\lambda(t-u)}dB_{u})ds+\int\limits_{0}^{t}X_{s}\lambda e^{\lambda s}ds$$

It feels like I am on the wrong track but I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter the expression for $dX_s$ into
$$
X_0+\int_0^te^{\lambda s}\,dX_s+\int_0^t X_s\lambda e^{\lambda s}\,ds
$$
you get
\begin{align}
e^{\lambda t}X_t&=X_0+\int_0^te^{\lambda s}\sqrt{2c\lambda}\,dB_s-\int_0^te^{\lambda s}\lambda X_s\,ds+\int_0^tX_s\lambda e^{\lambda s}\,ds\\
&=X_0+\int_0^te^{\lambda s}\sqrt{2c\lambda}\,dB_s
\end{align}
which immediately leads to the solution.

Alternatively, you can apply Ito's formula to the proposed solution
\begin{align}
X_t&=X_0e^{-\lambda t}+\sqrt{2c\lambda}\int_0^te^{-\lambda(t-s)}\,dB_s\\
&=e^{-\lambda t}\left\{X_0+\sqrt{2c\lambda}\int_0^te^{\lambda s}\,dB_s\right\}
\end{align}
which gives
\begin{align}
dX_t&=-\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\left\{X_0+\sqrt{2c\lambda}\int_0^te^{\lambda s}\,dB_s\right\}\,dt+e^{-\lambda t}\sqrt{2c\lambda}e^{\lambda t}\,dB_t\\
&=-\lambda X_t\,dt+\sqrt{2c\lambda}\,dB_t\,.
\end{align}

Comment: Ahh, I see that you proved it the other way around, i.e. if $dX_{t} = \sqrt{2c\lambda}dB_{t}-\lambda X_{t}dt \; \; (*)$ then $X_{t} = X_{0} + \sqrt{2c\lambda}\int_{0}^{t}e ^{-\lambda(t-s)}dB_{s} \; \; (**)$ but surely we want to actually prove the converse, namely that $(**)$ solves the SDE $(*)$, or is the above fact already sufficient?

Comment: First of all : your mistake was that you subsituted $X_s\,ds$ for $dX_s$ which is wrong. The above is sufficient. If you want to start with the solution $(**)$ and show it satisfies $(*)$ you can apply Ito's lemma to $(**)$. I recommend this as an exercise.

Comment: I do not know how to apply Ito's formula to the semimartingale of the form $X_{t} = X_{0}e^{-\lambda t} + \int_{0}^{t}e^{-\lambda(t-s)}dB_{s}$

Comment: See my last edit.